# Save documents with the data from mail merge

Tags: vba, ms-word

For my work I make product specifications. I have a table with all the data, and a standard Word document where the data needs to be inserted. I do this using the built-in mail merge function from Word. However, I need to save the documents seperately, and I found the following code for this:

```
Sub BreakOnSection()
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

   'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      Selection.Paste

   ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

     ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
     ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & DocNum & ".doc"
     ActiveDocument.Close
      ' Move the selection to the next section in the document
     Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

This saves the documents as test 1, test 2, etc.

I want to save the documents using one of the data items I use for the mail merge. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, this is the code I have now

```
Sub BreakOnSection()
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

   'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      Selection.Paste

      Dim rngParagraphs As Range
      Set rngParagraphs = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start + 6), End:=(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.End - 1))
      rngParagraphs.Select

   ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

     ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
     ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Productspec" & rngParagraphs & ".doc"
     ActiveDocument.Close
      ' Move the selection to the next section in the document
     Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```